# Unable to get navigation property(foreign key data) due to LazyLoading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have created MVC project with WebApi. And it is working fine but I am getting problem while fetching **navigation property (foreign key data)** in a details method of simple controller. I came to know that the problem is due to `LazyLoading` written in below code, in `DBEntities` constructor.

```
public DBEntities():base("name=GJ5ServiceProviderDBEntities")       
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;            
}
```

When I remove `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` line from above code then it is working fine for MVC project on that time I get all **navigation property (foreign key data)** but after that I am getting below error for WebApi:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.

**Fetching code**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
      if (id == null)
      {
          return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      }

      TableServiceProvider tableServiceProvider = 
          await db.TableServiceProviders.FindAsync(id);

      if (tableServiceProvider == null)
      {
           return HttpNotFound();
      }
      return View(tableServiceProvider);
 }
```

so is there any solution to solve above both problems ?

Comment: post your fetching code.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis i have added fetching code

Comment: just create another model , put all needed properties in that model and set the values from TableServiceProvider to the new model. Remove the actionresult return type and replace that  with the new model name.

Comment: you can refer this link to know how to use include to avoid lazyloading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607455/entity-framework-6-context-not-retrieving-navigation-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I will like to thanks `Frebin Francis` to his respose and help.

I could solve above problem just adding a single line in my Code.`db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;`

This code work for me.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        TableServiceProvider tableServiceProvider = await db.TableServiceProviders.FindAsync(id);
        if (tableServiceProvider == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(tableServiceProvider);
    }
```