# Do objects already loaded into the DbContext prevent further queries during lazy loading for the same object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, lazy-loading, dbcontext

My googlefu is weak and can't seem to find an answer to this, though I am sure it's out there.

Say you are using EF code first with lazy loading. You have a `Customer` entity and a `CustomerType` entity. You want to format this info to a grid display where the `CustomerType.Name` is displayed in a model before passing to the view. You iterate through 10 customers, which have a total of 3 customer types. Once customertypeA is loaded into the context from 1 lazily loaded query, will EF still send another DB query when it comes across the same CustomerTypeId foreign key in the customer?

I was recently learning about lazy loading vs eager loading. And I thought eager loading could help speed up some slow loading, but it in fact made them even slower. So I was wondering if something like first doing a query to just load all `CustomerTypes` into the DbConext before iterating over `Customers` would be possible to prevent 10 separate queries in the case of iterating over 10 customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Will EF still send another DB query when it comes across the same CustomerTypeId foreign key in the customer?**

No, it is only the first time if the entity with specified id has not been loaded, after the entity is loaded it will be tracked in the [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) data. The next lazy loading with the same id will not load from database.

When doing eager loading you will load the navigation property together with the main entity. This will only return 1 query with join statement to the child entity.

When doing lazy loading you will load the child entity when it is accessed. This will return 1 main query and each child query (if it hasn't been loaded).

Another post mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897006/968303) said that lazy loading wins, but you need to remember that to be able to have lazy loading, you need to keep the context alive.

More: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#lazy)

Comment: Hmm alright, so then I'll have to try my idea to see if I can get some performance improvements. It would result in two less complex queries and a smaller data set compared to eager loading, and less queries than using lazy loading (albiet in my example in the question only 1ess, but it could be way more in reality). Do you happen to know if this still works even if the FK property isn't exposed on the POCO? I presume even if the POCO doesn't expose it, EF still has it behind the scenes.

Comment: @DOTang, if there is no FK reference (only FK value), I think there is nothing to load for either eager or lazy loading

Comment: I just meant that the FK property is not exposed on the POCO. So customer would only have a customerType object on it, not also a customerTypeId, but I don't believe it matters.

Answer (score 1):

The only speed difference you gain from in eager-loading vs lazy-loading is removing latency in the database connection. An eager load is inherently a more complex query that a lazy load because you're introducing joins. However, by pulling all the data in one query instead of multiple queries, you're removing the sum latency between request and response for those additional queries. The theory, which is usually true, is that the extra network communication  from the multiple, simpler queries takes longer than the the additional processing time at the database required to load the single, more complex query.

However, there's exceptions to every rule. If you're eager loading huge tables with millions of rows, it's very likely that it will actually take the server longer to construct the result set than lazy-loading just the results you need would have taken. Eager-loading is not a magic bullet; its use needs to be evaluated on a case by case basis.

Although, if your eager-load is taking longer than lazy-loading, it would probably actually be better to investigate using a stored procedure instead of just falling back to lazy-loading. I've found very few instances where lazy-loading is actually the most efficient way.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer my question.

Comment: I'm interested on this part `Although, if your eager-load is taking longer than lazy-loading`, e.g. there are 2 customers, with 1 customer type that is referenced by both customers, Will eager loading return like 4 records (2 customers, 2 customer types) or 3 records (2 customers and 1 customer type) ? (since I'm not sure how to check the actual blob / data that is returned by the query)

Comment: @YuliamChandra: Sort of both. The actual result set from the database with have 2 customers joined with the same customer type row. That's technically just two records, but it's like 4 condensed to 2. However, Entity Framework will instantiate 2 `Customer` instances and just 1 `CustomerType` instance which both customers will reference.