# Entity Framework - Add objects depending on ForeignKey

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, design-patterns

I'm working on a semi-enterprise WPF Application, using EF6+ (any version is okay, I can update it any time I like).

I already have the database set-up (from previous project, it's a MSSQL db), and I'm doing code first obviously. I'll use mock objects due to NDA.

I would like to know what to do in order for EF to inject `Son` object from the database into the `Man` object as marked by Foreign Key.
e.g.:

```
[Table("Man")]
public class Man : ObservableObject
{
    private int _id;

    private int _sonId;
    private Son _son;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set => Set(() => Id, ref _id, value);
    }

    [ForeignKey("SonId")]
    public Son Son
    {
        get => _son;
        set => Set(() => Son, ref _son, value);
    }

    public int SonId
    {
        get => _sonId;
        set => Set(() => SonId, ref _sonId, value);
    }
}

[Table("Son")]
public class Son : ObservableObject
{
    private int _id;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set => Set(() => Id, ref _id, value);
    }
}
```

I properly retrieve (using their respective repositories) objects from the database, however the Foreign Key object (`Son`) is not mapped (it's null). Is this not an option in EF or I'm doing something wrong?

Repository

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Man>> GetAll()
{
    using (var ctx = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return await ctx.Men.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I did not use any `[Key]` annotation, because I assume EF associates Id field as a primary key since my table PK is `Id`, and I have some validation in other classes like `[StringLength]` and `[Range(1,10)]`, etc... Which I assume is not relevant for this problem.

Comment: Try `ctx.Men.Include(m => m.Son).ToListAsync();`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1). Also, since you prefer to skip the [Key] annotations you can also skip [Table] when it is the same name as the class and [ForeignKey] when it is the nav name + Id. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, and yes this was my solution. Thanks for additional links :) I'll check it out. Can you respond as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Also, is there a way to mark several objects to be injected at once instead of adding several .Include().Include().Include() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF6 you can use [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1) to eager load your child objects. I am not aware of a way to load multiple children without chaining Includes. You could create an extension method for loading all the children as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512285/entity-framework-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-eager-load-child-entities-wit). Also note there are some changes with [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

BTW, your class could be simplified if you are not altering the backing fields:

```
public class Man : ObservableObject  // ToTable Man by default
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //PK by convention

    public int SonId { get; set; } // FK by convention
    public Son Son { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll implement it using Extension Methods.