# Returning Json data in Entity Framework in API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, postgresql, entity-framework

I want to create an API for retrieving all the Companies with Employees in Json. I've got the problem sort of joining 2 tables. Look at the code:

**Tables**:

```
public class Company : BaseEntity
{
    public int CompanyId{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}
    public List <Employee> Workers { get; set; }
    public Company()
    {
        Workers = new List<Employee>();
    }
}

public class Employee : BaseEntity
{
    public int EmployeeId{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public string Email{get;set;}
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/companies")]
    public async Task<List<Company>>  ShowAllCompanies()
    {
        return await _context.Companies.Include(w=>w.Workers).ToListAsync();; 
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/employees")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ShowAllEmployees()
    {
        var result  = await _context.Employees.Include(c=>c.Company).ToListAsync();
        return Json(result);
    }
```

When I include each foreign table I get only one object in Json. If I do not include anything - I've got all the list of objects to show.

**With Include(w=>w.Workers)**
 [image: With Include(w=>w.Workers)]

**WITHOUT Include(w=>w.Workers**
[image: WITHOUT Include(w=>w.Workers)]

What is the problem to display all the workers within the company table?

Comment: It's not clear what's the problem here. What do you want to happen that's not happening?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I want to return an array of objects like on the second screenshot, but having access to all of the workers in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need the "Include()" to eager load.
See here for a similar question:
[Entity Framework - Is there a way to automatically eager-load child entities without Include()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512285/entity-framework-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-eager-load-child-entities-wit)