# Why output is 5?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to add 2 more functions to my delegate but it seems it doesn't process the functions I added. Following program outputs 5. I expect 10. Why is this the case?

```
using System;

namespace abc
{
public delegate int Del(int k);

class Class1
{
    public int Add2(int value)
    {
        return value = value + 2;
    }

    public int Add3(int value)
    {
        return value = value + 3;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        Del mydel = c.Add2;
        mydel += c.Add3;
        mydel += c.Add2;

        Console.WriteLine(mydel(3));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `mydel(3)` doesn't actually change the value of the argument, so you get the result of the last function which is `Add2(3)` which is 3+2 so 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens when you call `mydel(3)` is this:

1. `Add2(3)` is called. This returns `3 + 2` = 5, the return value of which is discarded.
2. `Add3(3)` is called. This returns `3 + 3` = 6, the return value of
   which is discarded.
3. `Add2(3)` is called. This returns `3 + 2` = 5, the return value of which is printed.

When you chain delegates, the return value of one is NOT passed as a parameter to a chained one.

Note that the delegates are called in LIFO order.

If you want to see how to actually chain functions together using delegates, [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8728686/106159).

Alternatively, as per the linked answer (and as mentioned by Toskr in the comments below), you can use `GetInvocationList()` and `DynamicInvoke()` to chain the methods together, but this is a very unusual thing to do:

```
static void Main()
{
    Class1 c = new Class1();
    Del mydel = c.Add2;
    mydel += c.Add3;
    mydel += c.Add2;

    int result = 3;

    foreach (var func in mydel.GetInvocationList())
    {
        result = (int)func.DynamicInvoke(result);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: beat me to it, i was half way through roughly this :)

Comment: also you forgot the first call to `Add2(3)`, and last is also `Add2(3)` not `Add3(2)`.

Comment: Is it possible to save the outputs and use it on next call?

Comment: @Rafalon Thanks; fixed. :)

Comment: @Lyrk Of course. But why? You should really have a good reason for doing hacks like this. Multicast delegates are designed for events, and events shouldn't have return values at all.

Comment: @Lyrk See the link at the end of my answer.

Comment: Just because I am wondering. I am studying C# and there are lots of things flying in my mind.

Comment: @MatthewWatson in order : `Add2(3) -> 3+2 = 5` discarded | `Add3(3) -> 3+3 = 6` discarded | `Add2(3) -> 3+2 = 5` printed

Comment: Disappointed :( There is a way for him to do this without using the more convoluted way, but the question is closed. He can simply get the invocation list and concat them to a single int for a response value.